# Properly using Obj-C library in Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, augmented-reality

edit: I think it might be about loading .xib from objective-c library and displaying it on swift's view controller

---

I've been trying to use https://github.com/promet/PRAugmentedReality library in a swift app.

It works perfectly with obj-c, like: [image]

But when i bridge it to swift project it starts to act like this: [image]

Below you can see my steps when i integrated this library to my swift project, codes of my swift project and download link for both objective-c and swift projects. Also here are youtube videos for PR Augmented Reality Framework:

Link 1: [Getting Started -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdN0XAoZXOY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdN0XAoZXOY)

Link 2: [Walkthrough of Internals-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xmx-0OnzTPY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xmx-0OnzTPY)

Swift project steps:

1. Creating a single view application with Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002) named demoAR
2. I add Foundation.framework, CoreGraphics.framework and UIKit.framework from Targets -> demoAR -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries
3. Then, File -> New Target -> Cocoa Touch Framework and clicked Next
4. Created a Target which has these properties: Product Name: PRAR , Language: Objective-C and Organization Identifier: com.timur.PRAR then I clicked Finish
   [image]
5. I created another group under PRAR and named it as "Classes", Then i copied files from Classes folder of framework and added them to PRAR/Classes folder.
6. I changed each .h files of framework's Target Membership to "Public"

[image: List item]

7. Then i imported header files to my bridging file (PRAR.h) like this

   ```
   #import <PRAR/ARSettings.h>
   #import <PRAR/PRARManager.h>
   #import <PRAR/ARController.h>
   #import <PRAR/ARObject.h>
   #import <PRAR/ARRadar.h>
   #import <PRAR/LocationMath.h>
   ```
8. Rest of what is did in order to run this framework within my swift project remains in my ViewController.swift file such as:

   ```
   import UIKit
   import PRAR
   var prARManager = PRARManager()
   let x: Int32 = AR_VIEW_TAG
   let y = Int(x)
   class ViewController: UIViewController, PRARManagerDelegate{

       func alert(title: String, withDetails details: String) {
           print("alert function")
           let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: title, message: details, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok", otherButtonTitles: "")
           alert.show()
       }

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
           print("1")
           // AŞAĞIDAKİ SATIRDA BİR SORUN VAR!!!
           prARManager = PRARManager.init(size: self.view.frame.size, delegate: self, showRadar: true)
           print("2")
       }

       override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
           print("3")
           let locationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.085468, longitude: 29.044033)
           print("4")
           prARManager.startARWithData(self.getDummyData() as [AnyObject], forLocation: locationCoordinates)
           print("5")
       }

       func getDummyData() -> NSArray {
           print("6")
           let dummyData: [AnyObject] = [["id": 0, "lat": 40.9780919, "lon": 27.511674, "title": "Tekirdağ"], ["id": 1, "lat": 40.8025157, "lon": 29.4397941, "title": "Gebze"]]
           print("7")
           return dummyData;
       }

       func prarDidSetupAR(arView: UIView, withCameraLayer cameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, andRadarView radar: UIView) {
           print("8")
           NSLog("Finished displaying ARObjects")
           print("9")
           self.view.layer.addSublayer(cameraLayer)
           print("10")
           self.view!.addSubview(arView)
           print("11")
           self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.view.viewWithTag(y)!)
           //self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.view!.viewWithTag(AR_VIEW_TAG));
           //self.view!.bringSubviewToFront(self.view!.viewWithTag( 042313 )!)
           //print("12")
           self.view.addSubview(radar)
           //print("13")
       }

       func prarUpdateFrame(arViewFrame: CGRect) {
           print("14")
           self.view.viewWithTag(y)?.frame = arViewFrame
           print("hello")
           //self.view.viewWithTag(AR_VIEW_TAG)!.frame = arViewFrame
           //self.view!.viewWithTag(042313)!.frame = arViewFrame
           print("15")
       }

       func prarGotProblem(problemTitle: String!, withDetails problemDetails: String!) {
           print("16")
           self.alert(problemTitle, withDetails: problemDetails)
           print("17")
       }
   }
   ```

Below you can download the objective-c and swift projects. I just want swift project to be able to run as objective-c project. How can i do that? I'm constantly walking through all framework and my code but i cannot see something wrong. *ps: I'm using Xcode version 7.2.1

Swift project's link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-cDfWHidgvcYnFNcnlMZG1aaDg/view?usp=sharing

Objective-C project's link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-cDfWHidgvcQUFXbktYSE5CeHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *ps: I tried to format as much as i can but it seems something wrong with stackoverflow right now. Can't format code properly..

Comment: I think it might be about loading .xib from objective-c library and displaying it on swift's view controller. Any ideas??..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add framework resources to you Swift project, see the Obj-C project:

[image]

compared to Swift project:

[image]

Make sure all the necessary images and xibs have target membership in "demoAR":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your Obj-C project, you'll see the image files (like RadarMV.png) are assigned to the app target. But in the Swift project, they're assigned to the PRAR target. So the app just isn't finding the images it's trying to load.

You could modify the code to find the images in the PRAR bundle. But a quicker solution (maybe not better) is to just assign the images to the app target:

[image: Image Targets]

This was enough to get things working for me.

Comment: Any idea if i want to use This library in Landscape Camera view in iPhone ?